# how does SQLAlchemy InvalidRequestError('Transaction XXX is not on the active transaction list) happen?

Tags: mysql, session, sqlalchemy

Recently I've got a SQLAlchemy InvalidRequestError.
The error log shows:

```
InvalidRequestError: Transaction <sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction object at
0x106830dd0> is not on the active transaction list
```

In what circumstance this error will be raised???

-----Edit----

```
# the following two line actually in my decorator
s = Session()
s.add(model1)

# refer to <http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/>
s2 = Session().using_bind('master')

model2 = s2.query(Model2).with_lockmode('update').get(1)
model2.somecolumn = 'new'

s2.commit()
```

This exception is raised

-----Edit2 -----

```
s = Session().using_bind('master')


model = Model(user_id=123456)
s.add(model)
s.flush() 
# here, raise the exception. 
# I add log in get_bind() of RoutingSession. when doing 'flush', the _name is None, and it returns engines['slave'].  
#If I use commit() instead of flush(), then it commits successfully
```

I change the using_bind method as the following and it works well.

```
def using_bind(self, name):
    self._name = name
    return self
```

The previous RoutingSession:

```
class RoutingSession(Session):
    _name = None                                                                                                                                                

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):   
        logger.info(self._name)         
        if self._name:                                                                           
            return engines[self._name]                                          
        elif self._flushing:                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            logger.info('master')                                                  
            return engines['master']                                               
        else:                                                                      
            logger.info('slave')    
            return engines['slave']

    def using_bind(self, name):                              
        s = RoutingSession()                                                      
        vars(s).update(vars(self))   
        s._name = name                                                                    
        return s
```

Answer (score 3):

that's an internal assertion which should never occur.    There's no way to answer this question without at least a full stack trace, if perhaps you are improperly using the Session in a concurrent fashion, or manipulating its internals.  I can only show that exception raised if I manipulate private methods or state pertaining to the Session object.

Here's that:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

s = Session()
s2 = Session()

t = s.transaction
t2 = s2.transaction

s2.transaction = t   # nonsensical assignment of the SessionTransaction
                     # from one Session to also be referred to by another,
                     # corrupts the transaction chain by leaving out "t2".
                     # ".transaction" should never be assigned to on the outside

t2.rollback()  # triggers the assertion case
```

basically, the above should never happen, since you're not supposed to assign to ".transaction".  that's a read-only attribute.

Comment: hi, zzzeek. I have to use Master Session(refer to the example in your article) to lock some row. (See Edit2) And the exception raised again. I don't know how to fix

Comment: it's likely this: `vars(s).update(vars(self))`.  When using a 3rd party library, you can't just take the internal state from one of it's objects and shove it into another.  That internal state can have any number of attachments and dependencies back to the parent object.